# What does this C compiler error mean?

Tags: c, function, compiler-construction

This error keeps on showing up everytime I compile my program:

```
 ch.c: In function 'my_ch':
 ch.c:8:1: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '{'
     token
 ch.c:20:1: error: expected '{' at end of input
```

But I think I got my format right:

```
void my_ch ()
{
    /*some initialization stuff here*/

    while ( /*conditions here*/ ) {
        /*insert some code here*/
    }

return;
}
```

My 8th line is the one after the `void my_ch ()` and the 20th is the one after `return;`. Does anyone have a clue why the error keeps on showing up? Thanks a lot

**EDIT**

```
//ch
#include <stdio.h>
#include "ch.h"
#define BUFLEN 2500
#define MAC 3000
<space>
```

The seventh line is the `void my_ch()` line

Comment: Why the redundant return?

Comment: Syntax error in an included file? That sort of error is usually due to an earlier syntax error.

Comment: Can you show us what you have before the function declaration?  Paste in the lines 1-7, is what I mean.  I suspect that the problem lies there.

Comment: You may have forgotten a semicolon at the end of a class/struct in an include.  Or something like that.

Comment: If only these lines, there are no error. You have to show more code.

Comment: Important life lesson here... the line the compiler identifies with the error on isn't always the line where the problem is (it's often right before the one it complains about when this happens, however).

Comment: Next step: What's at the very end of "ch.h"?  Or, if you have a file containing `#include "ch.h"` and nothing else, does that compile?

Comment: @FatalError Especially in C/C++. Errors tend to be very cryptic and rarely point directly to what needs to be fixed.

Comment: Instead of making everyone guess, why don't you just post both the .h and .c files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something is unfinished in ch.h.  Maybe something like a function prototype with a missing semicolon at the end.  What is in ch.h?

Answer (score 1):

ch.h probably has a struct declaration without a ';' after the closing '}'.

Comment: I did not use any struct declarations

Comment: @Sakamoto Then you have some other error in ch.h ... the one I mentioned is just a very common one.